# ¿Cómo pongo negritas, cursiva o subrayado en React Native?

Tags: react-native

Resulta que quiero coger un texto en React Nativo y subrayarlo, ponerle cursiva o negrita. Sé que en JavaScript haría `text-decoration: underline;` para subrayar, pero no me funciona aquí.

¿Cuál es la manera de hacerlo de forma fácil?

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50556937/1983854

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bastante está descrito en el artículo de React Native [*Text*](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html), pero sucintamente:

```
<Text style={styles.negrita}>¡Estoy en negrita!</Text>
<Text style={styles.cursiva}>¡Estoy en cursiva!</Text>
<Text style={styles.subrayado}>¡Estoy subrayado!</Text>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    negrita: {fontWeight: 'bold'},
    cursiva: {fontStyle: 'italic'},
    subrayado: {textDecorationLine: 'underline'}
})
```

Puedes verlo en Snack en modo demo: https://snack.expo.io/BJT2ss_y7

Respuesta adaptada de [How do I make text bold, italic, or underline in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50556938/1983854) escrita por James Ko.